# Lots of elif, is there a better way?

Tags: shell-script, control-flow

I have a Bash script that looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
#
FECHA=`date +%j`

if [ $FECHA -eq 40 ]
then
    echo "Esta semana le toca preparar el café a Osvaldo" | mail -s 'Café' mailgroup@somedomain.mx
    exit
elif [ $FECHA -eq 47 ]
then
    echo "Esta semana le toca preparar el café a Berenice" | mail -s 'Café' mailgroup@somedomain.mx
    exit
elif [ $FECHA -eq 54 ]
then
    echo "Esta semana le toca preparar el café a Nizaá" | mail -s 'Café' mailgroup@somedomain.mx
    exit
fi
```

which will run, thanks to crontab, every monday at 7 am.

The actual Bash script has more lines, because there are more people involved. I think it works. But... Is there a way to make this script with fewer lines?

I was thinking: two variables, one for the person that will make the coffee and another for the date and a way to relate those variables.

Comment: I don't suppose you have [`case` statements](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html) in mind?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the `case/esac` construct fits well here.

```
#!/bin/bash

case "`date +%j`" in
  40) name=Osvaldo ;;
  47) name=Berenice ;;
  54) name=Nizaá ;;
  *) exit ;;
esac

echo "Esta semana le toca preparar el café a ${name}" \
   | mail -s 'Café' mailgroup@somedomain.mx
```

Note: if the same person needs to make coffee several times, you can aggregate tests with `|`:

```
case "`date +%j`" in
  12|23|40|49) name=Osvaldo ;;
  10|19|30|47) name=Berenice ;;
...
```

Comment: I used to code with a style guide requiring `esac` to be followed by the comment `# is ridiculous`. Just to make sure you don't forget.

Answer (score 6):

This is a good case for an array. Here is an example:

```
mapping=([40]='Osvaldo'
         [47]='Berenice'
         [54]='Nizaá')

echo "Esta semana le toca preparar el café a ${mapping[FECHA]}" | mail -s 'Café' mailgroup@somedomain.mx
```

This eliminates the conditionals entirely.

Comment: This doesn't handle the case that `$FECHA` is not among those three - though the function in the question does. In fact this prints nonsense in that case, I think. This also gets a little dangerous if the value of `$FECHA` is not tested - a math substitution is nigh an `eval`.

Comment: According to `http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/shell.xml`:  If you find you need to use arrays for anything more than assignment of ${PIPESTATUS}, you should use Python. No downvote, it is a nice solution for configuring the names on another place than the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Put the names in a configfile, like coffee.txt:

```
040=Osvaldo
047=Berenice
054=Nizaá
```

When somebody is sick, fired or hired, you do not want to change your code:

```
name=$(grep "^$(date '+%j')=" coffee.txt | cut -d= -f2-)
echo "Esta semana le toca preparar el café a ${name}" \
   | mail -s 'Café' mailgroup@somedomain.mx
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set -- 40 Osvaldo 47 Bernice 54 Nizaá
[ "${FECHA#[54][074]}" = "${FECHA%"${FECHA#44}"}" ] &&
until    [ "$((${1#$FECHA}0&&$#))" -eq 0 ]         &&
         printf "${1+%s\n}" "Esta semana le toca preparar el café a $2"
do       shift 2; done
[ "$#" -gt 1 ] && mail -s 'Café' mailgroup@somedomain.mx
```

Comment: If I didn't know better, I'd say that's almost Perl-like. Write-only.

Comment: @muru - what's *Write-only*?

Comment: Something I'd be scared to modify: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-only_language, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702728/how-did-perl-gain-a-reputation-for-being-a-write-only-language :D

Comment: @muru - you could understand it if you tried. It just compares an acceptable case against an edge case each time it compares anything. Basically the problem is the names - it's easier to take in when it's all sequential arg numbers - stuff adds up in at case. Anyway, I find it easiest to allow values to test themselves - there's a lot less trouble to hunt down later on when you balance possibilities in the first place. Or, well, a lot less for me to hunt down.

Comment: I understood it ("If I didn't know better..."), but is very ... *terse*, I suppose would be the word. I was just commenting on how like Perl it is - mishmash of symbols and characters. :)

Comment: @muru - yeah, I don't expect it will garner much fanfare, but I prefer terse - trying to figure out which of the 20 50 line shell functions calls which based on which arbitrarily named variable in a shell script is - to me - exasperating. It's what bugs me most about `zsh`, actually. Though the features are great, taking it all in fairly well blows my mind. I keep a tiny little library of short shell functions that extend `dash` to my preferences. They're at most 10 or 20 lines a piece and fully replace builtins. They all just work by iterating args and returning correctly. That's what I value

Comment: @muru - anyway, the `case` answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

If each code block after an `if` condition ends in `exit`, then you don't need an `elif`; simply end the conditional with `fi`.

I'm also a big fan of putting the `then` on the same line as the `if` which makes the code shorter in linecount and easier (quicker) to read IMHO.
So your code becomes:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
FECHA=`date +%j`

if [ $FECHA -eq 40 ]; then
    echo "Esta semana le toca preparar el café a Osvaldo" | mail -s 'Café' mailgroup@somedomain.mx
    exit
fi
if [ $FECHA -eq 47 ]; then
    echo "Esta semana le toca preparar el café a Berenice" | mail -s 'Café' mailgroup@somedomain.mx
    exit
fi
if [ $FECHA -eq 54 ]; then
    echo "Esta semana le toca preparar el café a Nizaá" | mail -s 'Café' mailgroup@somedomain.mx
    exit
fi
```

Apart from that, in this case as the code is almost the same in each case here, I'd use Sam Hocevar's solution.

Comment: ? I don't understand the question... the `if` block is different in each case. And I already stated that Sam's answer would be more suited in this specific case.

Comment: Sometimes it makes sense to write code that's easily understood, even if it may be slightly less efficient. I've come to this conclusion after 30+ years of programming experience.

Comment: The question was about how to write code coe without all those `elif`s, not how to write the script in a totally different way. I think my answer adequately addresses the question. Again for the third time, I agree with Sam's answer which doesn't have any `if` so I don't get what you're trying to convince me of. Endof.

Comment: The answer doesn't answer the question enough. It's a very specific answer because not all ifs end in exit. The point of the question was to reduce code significantly, rather than just a few characters here and there.

Comment: The other answers already covered the "reduce code significantly" part (as I've said now for the 5th time), I just wanted to point out that you don't need an "else" part if the "if" part ends with `exit`, it's much easier to follow the thread of the program if unnecessary nesting is eliminated. Apparently a lot of people still don't get that point. I just hope those people don't write code I ever have to maintain or modify.